# Retrieve images from Firebase Database and display them on screen in my app

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get images from firebase database to display in my app in an Activity.The images upload successfully but when i try to view them,i dont see them.Here is my code to retrieve them from firebase.Im using android studio.

```
public class ActionBar22 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    private ImageAdapter madapter;

    private ProgressDialog mprogresscircle;

    private DatabaseReference mdatabaseref;
    private List<UploadedPosts> muploads;

    List<UploadedPosts> list = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar22);


       //pull items from firebase database
       mrecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
       mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mprogresscircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
        mprogresscircle = new ProgressDialog(ActionBar22.this);
        mprogresscircle.setMessage("Loading...");
        mprogresscircle.show();

        muploads = new ArrayList<>();

      final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       DatabaseReference ref  = database.getReference("Uploads");

                for(DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            UploadedPosts upload=postsnapshot.getValue(UploadedPosts.class);
                         muploads.add(upload);
                     }

                     madapter = new ImageAdapter(ActionBar22.this,muploads);

                     mrecyclerview.setAdapter(madapter);
                     mprogresscircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ActionBar22.this, databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mprogresscircle.dismiss();
                mprogresscircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

I want it to display one photo in the width of the screen.They be displayed in a column.The photos dont show.Only a blank screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ91s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide or Picasso for showing pictures in ImageViews, here is an example of how you can do it:

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

**Code:**

```
   Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(yourImageURLHere)
                .apply(RequestOptions.signatureOf(new CenterCrop()))
                .into(ImageView);
```

and here you can find some other examples: https://github.com/bumptech/glide , scroll down the page and check them.